# Instaparse: How to recognise a newline

Tags: instaparse

I want to parse the text of a file that contains newlines. The file could be in Windows or Unix, but for now it is a Windows file with this contents:

```
(**************
***************)
```

The above file contents has been read in with `slurp` and will contain a newline. Here is the grammar that I am trying to use:

```
S = start-comment stars <inside-comment>
start-comment = '('
stars = '*' +
<inside-comment> = '\n' +
```

This grammar is also slurped in from a file, which I believe makes things a little easier:

> "The only escape characters needed are the ordinary escape characters for strings and regular expressions (additionally, instaparse also supports \' inside single-quoted strings)."

The newline does not seem to be being parsed:

```
Parse error at line 1, column 16:
(**************
               ^
Expected one of:
"\n"
"*"
```

What do I need to set `<inside-comment>` to so that the error comes on the first star of the second line, which will indicate that the grammar has recognized the newline?

Answer (score 4):

Newlines in Windows show up as `\r\n` and in Unix as `\n`.  So you need something like this:

```
#'\r?\n'
```

Double the blackslashes if your grammar is inside a string:

```
"some-rule = #'\\r?\\n'"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, even with doubling the backslashes - just got similar 'Expected one of'

Comment: Sorry, the pound sign character got deleted by the form.  This should be a regex. `#'r?\n'`

Answer (score 0):

This parses to the end:

```
S = start-comment stars <inside-comment-1> stars end-comment
start-comment = '('
end-comment = ')'
stars = '*' +
<inside-comment-1> = '\n' | '\r\n'
<inside-comment-2> = '\r?\n'
```

Note that `<inside-comment-2>` does not work. While `<inside-comment-1>` works, there might be a more elegant way of getting past a newline??